# "return False" completely ignored?

Tags: python

So I'm working on a helper function to help with a recursion problem I recently received from class, and this is what it looks like:

```
def helper(a, b):
    if (a % b == 0 and b > 1):
        return False
    elif (a%b != 0 and b > 1):
        helper(a, b - 1)
```

If I put in something like (12, 11), I expect the result to be False, but I instead get met with None! Why does it do that? If I replace "return False" with a print statement, it comes out fine, so it seems like the return statement is being completely ignored. How should I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `return helper(a, b - 1)`

Answer (score 4):

You must return the result of the last line:

```
def helper(a, b):
    if a % b == 0 and b > 1:
        return False
    elif a % b != 0 and b > 1:
        return helper(a, b - 1)  # <--- Return a value here.
```

Also, if `b <= 1`, Python won't execute neither the `if` nor the `elif` branches.
In this case, the function will return `None`.

---

#### Why I must use `return` before the call to `helper`?

Let's examine the case in which a = 8, b = 5. `a % b != 0 and b > 0` is `True`, and the function will call `helper(8, 4)`.

`helper(8, 4)` is a new function call, which has nothing to do with `helper(8, 5)`. It will check if `a % b == 0 and b > 1` (which is `True`), and will return `False` to the place where `helper(8, 4)` was called from.

If there is no `return` statement before `helper(8, 4)`, your first function call (`helper(8, 5)`) will execute `helper(8, 4)` but won't do anything with the value returned from it.

You must use `return` to tell the caller what is the result of the execution.

Comment: Thanks for your good explanation

Comment: Thank you so much!